# Java RandomAccessFile read() returning 0x00

Tags: java

I'm using a Java RandomAccessFile seeking to 0x000000A0 of my file, then reading from that location into a byte array. However, every byte I read comes out to be 0x00. I'm not modifying the file anywhere else in this program, this is the only place. Also I know for a fact that there is data at 0x000000A0 of my file. Here it is:

```
public static String getGameCode() throws IOException
{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0x10];
    raf.seek(0x0000A0);
    raf.read(bytes);
    raf.close();

    for(byte b : bytes) {
        System.out.println(String.format("0x%02X", b));
    }

    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: What does `raf.read(bytes)` return?

Comment: Uh oh, it returns -1...?

Comment: So your file is 160 bytes or less in size. --- *FYI:* Never call `read()` without using the return value. E.g. you asked to read 16 bytes, but it might only read 7 bytes. The actual value returned must be used. You can never assume that the buffer is filled, even if you know there is bytes enough in the file.

Comment: It's not lol, it's 32MB in size, but something is obviously wrong with loading my file here. Time to do more searching.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my 32MB file was somehow erased and therefore was 0KB. I just replaced the file with a good copy and it works fine. Remember to confirm the size of your file!